# grepping text string returns no result

Tags: string, grep

I have to find a lot of information in the esxi host for configuration.

When I run commands like:

```
# grep -i "^Banner" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

I get no results but if I execute:

```
cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

I can see in file the string "Banner /etc/issue".

Why does grep not return the information requested?  What am I missing?

Comment: your example is working, please add your OS/distro informations to the question, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: Thanks Othman for your response.  I not at work and don't have access to the server at the moment but I'm using VMware ESXi 6.5.

Answer (score 1):

I would experiment with the searched file a bit.

Please try the following command:

```
cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -i '^Banner'
```

Or if it fails just

```
cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -i Banner
```

*(the word 'banner' anywhere).*

Further please try to copy the file to your local repository
and try examining with `vi sshd_config` to test if there aren't any non-visible characters in the file making the search insufficient.

It could be the hidden characters in the file, or that the searched string isn't located at start of the line (or combination of both.)